# Внутри ли камеры объект?

Tags: камера, unity3d

Есть два объекта на сцене и два объекта, следящие за каждым из них, камеры. Мне нужно, чтобы, если камера не видела "не свой объект" в гуи рисовалась стрелочка, указывающая направление на него. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь есть ответы которые ты ищешь:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html

Достаточно немного погуглить перед задаванием вопроса :)

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод камеры [`Camera.WorldToViewPortPoint()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html). Он преобразует координаты , в нормализованные координаты зоны видимости камеры, где левый нижний угол всегда (0,0), а правый верхний всегда (1,1), вне зависимости от разрешения камеры.

```
private Camera _cam;

private void Start()
{
  _cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

private void Update()
{
  var viewPortPoint = _cam.WorldToViewPortPoint(objectYouLookFor.position); // получишь нормальзованные экранные координаты 

  if(viewPortPoint.x < 0 || viewPortPoint.x > 1 || viewPortPoint.y < 0 || viewPortPoint.y > 1)
  {
    // твоя логика, когда объект вне зоны видимости камеры 
  }
}
```